# schema.org Microdata for headings in book

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Is there Microdata to capture headings in a book. The book itself is of type http://schema.org/Book.

I also have a webpage parent itemscope.

I want to get all the chapters in the book to display in as part of the Search results snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, `Book` doesn’t offer properties for headings of chapters.

You can only specify the title/name of the whole book ([`name`](http://schema.org/name), [`alternateName`](http://schema.org/alternateName), [`alternativeHeadline`](http://schema.org/alternativeHeadline)).

On a structural level, you could make statements about the webpage content, i.e., use [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) and its [`name`](http://schema.org/name) for every chapter. But this would have no relation to the `Book`.